# YUV to RGB conversion by fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, shader, fragment-shader

I've a problem with convertion of camera preview in Android from YUV format to RGB. The purpose of conversion is to apply some effects. I try to convert by fragment shader because convertion by native code is slow (about 14fps). The reference which I've used is http://jyrom.tistory.com/m/post/view/id/187. I try to port this code to Android platform, but the result is black-green rectangles. But, I can watch some form through the output which I get. Could you please try to help me to resolve this issue. I believe this is popular problem: apply effects to camera preview. I also give a link to my project for testing: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12829395/application/FilterGL/FilterGL.zip.
Thank you.

UPDATED:

This is my **onPreviewFrame** method:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    yBuffer.put(data);
    yBuffer.position(0);

    System.arraycopy(data, U_INDEX, uData, 0, LENGTH_4 * 2);
    uBuffer.put(uData);
    uBuffer.position(0);

    System.arraycopy(data, V_INDEX, vData, 0, LENGTH_4);
    vBuffer.put(vData);
    vBuffer.position(0);
}
```

This is how I bind byte arrays to OpenGL texture in **onDrawFrame** method:

```
    GLES20.glUniform1i(yTexture, 1);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(   GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
            320, 240, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yBuffer);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    GLES20.glUniform1i(uTexture, 2);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(   GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
            160, 120, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, uBuffer);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    GLES20.glUniform1i(vTexture, 3);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(   GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
            160, 120, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vBuffer);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
```

And this is my fragment shader code:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D y_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D v_texture;

void main()
{   
    float nx,ny,r,g,b,y,u,v;
    nx=v_texCoord.x;
    ny=v_texCoord.y;
    y=texture2D(y_texture,v_texCoord).r;
    u=texture2D(u_texture,v_texCoord).r;
    v=texture2D(v_texture,v_texCoord).r;

    y=1.1643*(y-0.0625);
    u=u-0.5;
    v=v-0.5;

    r=y+1.5958*v;
    g=y-0.39173*u-0.81290*v;
    b=y+2.017*u;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(r,g,b,1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you have already fixed this problem.My answer

1. By default Camera output is NV12, but in fragment shader YUV to RGB you are using  YV12 -> RGB.
   You will have to do 
   `setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);`, or may be use some other shader
2. There are 3 textures , make sure you do

   `GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);`
   `GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, muTextureName)`

   before call to any  glTexImage2D. and glTexSubImage2D
3. You can also use glTexSubImage2D with every frame and glTexImage2D once.
4. size of U and V is same , atleast for YV12,

   `System.arraycopy(data, U_INDEX, uData, 0, LENGTH_4 * 2);`

   should be
   `System.arraycopy(data, U_INDEX, uData, 0, LENGTH_4);`
    change the size accordingly in the code.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you solved your problem.

I used your code and I solved in this mode.

```
public class MyRenderer implements Renderer{
public static final int recWidth = Costanti.recWidth;
public static final int recHeight = Costanti.recHeight;

private static final int U_INDEX = recWidth*recHeight;
private static final int V_INDEX = recWidth*recHeight*5/4;
private static final int LENGTH = recWidth*recHeight;
private static final int LENGTH_4 = recWidth*recHeight/4;

private int previewFrameWidth = 256;
private int previewFrameHeight = 256;

private int[] yTextureNames;
private int[] uTextureNames;
private int[] vTextureNames;

private MainActivity activity;

private FloatBuffer mVertices;
private ShortBuffer mIndices;

private int mProgramObject;
private int mPositionLoc;
private int mTexCoordLoc;

private int yTexture;
private int uTexture;
private int vTexture;

private final float[] mVerticesData = { -1.f, 1.f, 0.0f, // Position 0
        0.0f, 0.0f, // TexCoord 0
        -1.f, -1.f, 0.0f, // Position 1
        0.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 1
        1.f, -1.f, 0.0f, // Position 2
        1.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 2
        1.f, 1.f, 0.0f, // Position 3
        1.0f, 0.0f // TexCoord 3
};
private final short[] mIndicesData = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

private ByteBuffer yBuffer;
private ByteBuffer uBuffer;
private ByteBuffer vBuffer;

private IntBuffer frameBuffer;
private IntBuffer renderBuffer;
private IntBuffer parameterBufferWidth;
private IntBuffer parameterBufferHeigth;

byte[] ydata = new byte[LENGTH];
byte[] uData = new byte[LENGTH_4];
byte[] vData = new byte[LENGTH_4];

public MyRenderer(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;

    mVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVerticesData.length * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mVertices.put(mVerticesData).position(0);

    mIndices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mIndicesData.length * 2)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
    mIndices.put(mIndicesData).position(0);

    yBuffer = MyGraphUtils.makeByteBuffer(LENGTH);
    uBuffer = MyGraphUtils.makeByteBuffer(LENGTH_4/* * 2*/);
    vBuffer = MyGraphUtils.makeByteBuffer(LENGTH_4);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE);
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    Log.d("debug", "on surface created");
    // Define a simple shader program for our point.
    final String vShaderStr = readTextFileFromRawResource(activity, R.raw.v_simple);
    final String fShaderStr = readTextFileFromRawResource(activity, R.raw.f_convert);
    frameBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    renderBuffer= IntBuffer.allocate(1);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBuffer);
    GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, renderBuffer);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer.get(0));
    GLES20.glClear(0);
    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer.get(0));     

    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16,
                                 320, 240);

    parameterBufferHeigth = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    parameterBufferWidth = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    GLES20.glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, parameterBufferWidth);
    GLES20.glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, parameterBufferHeigth);
    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer.get(0));
    if (GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER)!=GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
        Log.d("debug", "gl frame buffer status != frame buffer complete");
    }
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glClear(0);

    mProgramObject = loadProgram(vShaderStr, fShaderStr);

    // Get the attribute locations
    mPositionLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "a_position");
    mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "a_texCoord");

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    yTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "y_texture");
    yTextureNames = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, yTextureNames, 0);
    int yTextureName = yTextureNames[0];

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    uTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "u_texture");
    uTextureNames = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, uTextureNames, 0);
    int uTextureName = uTextureNames[0];

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    vTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "v_texture");
    vTextureNames = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, vTextureNames, 0);
    int vTextureName = vTextureNames[0];

    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

@Override
public final void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    Log.d("debug", "on Draw frame");
    // Clear the color buffer
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use the program object
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramObject);

    // Load the vertex position
    mVertices.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionLoc, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5*4, mVertices);
    // Load the texture coordinate
    mVertices.position(3);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5*4, mVertices);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionLoc);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, yTextureNames[0]);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(   GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
            320, 240, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yBuffer);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, yTextureNames[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(yTexture, 0);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, uTextureNames[0]);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(   GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
            160, 120, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, uBuffer);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1+2);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, uTextureNames[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(uTexture, 2);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, vTextureNames[0]);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(   GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
            160, 120, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vBuffer);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1+1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, vTextureNames[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(vTexture, 1);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices);
}



public void setPreviewFrameSize(int realWidth, int realHeight) {
    previewFrameHeight = realHeight;
    previewFrameWidth = realWidth;
}

public static String readTextFileFromRawResource(final Context context, final int resourceId) {
    final InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
    final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    String nextLine;
    final StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            body.append(nextLine);
            body.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return body.toString();
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderSrc) {
    int shader;
    int[] compiled = new int[1];

    // Create the shader object
    shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    if (shader == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Load the shader source
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderSrc);
    // Compile the shader
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
    // Check the compile status
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);

    if (compiled[0] == 0) {
        Log.e("ESShader", GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
        return 0;
    }
    return shader;
}

public static int loadProgram(String vertShaderSrc, String fragShaderSrc) {
    int vertexShader;
    int fragmentShader;
    int programObject;
    int[] linked = new int[1];

    // Load the vertex/fragment shaders
    vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertShaderSrc);
    if (vertexShader == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragShaderSrc);
    if (fragmentShader == 0) {
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        return 0;
    }

    // Create the program object
    programObject = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    if (programObject == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    GLES20.glAttachShader(programObject, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(programObject, fragmentShader);

    // Link the program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(programObject);

    // Check the link status
    GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programObject, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linked, 0);

    if (linked[0] == 0) {
        Log.e("ESShader", "Error linking program:");
        Log.e("ESShader", GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programObject));
        GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programObject);
        return 0;
    }

    // Free up no longer needed shader resources
    GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    return programObject;
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    System.arraycopy(data, 0, ydata, 0, LENGTH);
    yBuffer.put(ydata);
    yBuffer.position(0);

    System.arraycopy(data, U_INDEX, uData, 0, LENGTH_4);
    uBuffer.put(uData);
    uBuffer.position(0);

    System.arraycopy(data, V_INDEX, vData, 0, LENGTH_4);
    vBuffer.put(vData);
    vBuffer.position(0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

For the fastest and most optimized way, just use the common GL Extention

```
//Fragment Shader
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture;
```

Than in Java

```
surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textureIDs[0]);
try {
   someCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
} catch (IOException t) {
   Log.e(TAG, "Cannot set preview texture target!");
}

someCamera.startPreview();

private static final int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;
```

In Java GL Thread

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureIDs[0]);
GLES20.glUniform1i(uTextureHandle, 0);
```

The color conversion is already done for you.
You can do what ever you want right in the Fragment shader.

Hope that saves you some time in your research.

Answer (score 1):

Finally made your project display camera previews. 
I found 2 problems:
1. Before binding and changing surface characteristics you have to call GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.surfacenumber);
2. More important and hidden problem is that 
GLES20.glTexImage2D() does not work with width and height, which are not power of 2 numbers. 
After loading texture with size, for example, 1024X1024, you should call GLES20.glTexSubImage2D()

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I applied the solution form [How to render Android's YUV-NV21 camera image on the background in libgdx with OpenGLES 2.0 in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456884/how-to-render-androids-yuv-nv21-camera-image-on-the-background-in-libgdx-with-o) to the project shared in the question and got a working project. If you are like me searching for tutorial code that does YUV to RGB conversion by fragment shader, you can simply do the following steps to get a working example.

1. Download the project https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12829395/application/FilterGL/FilterGL.zip and unzip.
2. Replace file **GLRenderer.java** and **res/raw/f_convert.glsl** entirely by the code shared below.
3. Open the project in Eclipse, or [import the project to Android Studio](https://www.google.com.hk/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&rlz=1C1ASUM_enHK688HK688&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=import%20to%20android%20studio&oq=imp&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i65j0l3.2519j0j7).

The main issues of the code in the question are:

1. without **GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);**, yBuffer is not passed to GL.
2. the YUV data takes YUV-NV21 format, and u_texture and v_texture wasn't passed and handled correctly in the shader. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456884/how-to-render-androids-yuv-nv21-camera-image-on-the-background-in-libgdx-with-o) for more information.

Now the corrected code: please replace **GLRenderer.java** with

```
package com.filtergl.shader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.util.Log;

public class GLRenderer
implements Renderer, PreviewCallback {
    private static final int LENGTH = 76800;
    private static final int LENGTH_2 = 38400;

    private ActivityFilterGL activity;

    private FloatBuffer mVertices;
    private ShortBuffer mIndices;

    private int previewFrameWidth = 256;
    private int previewFrameHeight = 256;
    private int mProgramObject;
    private int mPositionLoc;
    private int mTexCoordLoc;
//  private int mSamplerLoc;
    private int yTexture;
    private int uTexture;
    private int vTexture;

    private final float[] mVerticesData = { -1.f, 1.f, 0.0f, // Position 0
            0.0f, 0.0f, // TexCoord 0
            -1.f, -1.f, 0.0f, // Position 1
            0.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 1
            1.f, -1.f, 0.0f, // Position 2
            1.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 2
            1.f, 1.f, 0.0f, // Position 3
            1.0f, 0.0f // TexCoord 3
    };

    private final short[] mIndicesData = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

    private ByteBuffer frameData = null;
    private ByteBuffer yBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer uBuffer;

    public GLRenderer(ActivityFilterGL activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        mVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVerticesData.length * 4)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mVertices.put(mVerticesData).position(0);

        mIndices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mIndicesData.length * 2)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        mIndices.put(mIndicesData).position(0);

        yBuffer = GraphicsUtil.makeByteBuffer(LENGTH);
        uBuffer = GraphicsUtil.makeByteBuffer(LENGTH_2);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Clear the color buffer
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use the program object
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramObject);

        // Load the vertex position
        mVertices.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionLoc, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, mVertices);
        // Load the texture coordinate
        mVertices.position(3);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, mVertices);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionLoc);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);

        GLES20.glUniform1i(yTexture, 1);
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(   GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
                320, 240, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yBuffer);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);

        GLES20.glUniform1i(uTexture, 2);
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(   GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA,
                160, 120, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, uBuffer);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        // Define a simple shader program for our point.
        final String vShaderStr = readTextFileFromRawResource(activity, R.raw.v_simple);
        final String fShaderStr = readTextFileFromRawResource(activity, R.raw.f_convert);

        // Load the shaders and get a linked program object
        mProgramObject = loadProgram(vShaderStr, fShaderStr);

        // Get the attribute locations
        mPositionLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "a_position");
        mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "a_texCoord");

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        yTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "y_texture");
        int[] yTextureNames = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, yTextureNames, 0);
        int yTextureName = yTextureNames[0];
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, yTextureName);

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        uTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "u_texture");
        int[] uTextureNames = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, uTextureNames, 0);
        int uTextureName = uTextureNames[0];
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, uTextureName);

        // Set the background clear color to black.
        GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    public void setPreviewFrameSize(int realWidth, int realHeight) {
        previewFrameHeight = realHeight;
        previewFrameWidth = realWidth;

//      frameData = GraphicsUtil.makeByteBuffer(previewFrameHeight * previewFrameWidth * 3);
    }

    public static String readTextFileFromRawResource(final Context context, final int resourceId) {
        final InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String nextLine;
        final StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while ((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                body.append(nextLine);
                body.append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return body.toString();
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderSrc) {
        int shader;
        int[] compiled = new int[1];

        // Create the shader object
        shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
        if (shader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        // Load the shader source
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderSrc);
        // Compile the shader
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        // Check the compile status
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);

        if (compiled[0] == 0) {
            Log.e("ESShader", GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            return 0;
        }
        return shader;
    }

    public static int loadProgram(String vertShaderSrc, String fragShaderSrc) {
        int vertexShader;
        int fragmentShader;
        int programObject;
        int[] linked = new int[1];

        // Load the vertex/fragment shaders
        vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertShaderSrc);
        if (vertexShader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragShaderSrc);
        if (fragmentShader == 0) {
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
            return 0;
        }

        // Create the program object
        programObject = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        if (programObject == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        GLES20.glAttachShader(programObject, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programObject, fragmentShader);

        // Link the program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(programObject);

        // Check the link status
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programObject, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linked, 0);

        if (linked[0] == 0) {
            Log.e("ESShader", "Error linking program:");
            Log.e("ESShader", GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programObject));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programObject);
            return 0;
        }

        // Free up no longer needed shader resources
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

        return programObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        yBuffer.put(data, 0, LENGTH);
        yBuffer.position(0);

        uBuffer.put(data, LENGTH, LENGTH/2);
        uBuffer.position(0);
    }

}
```

and replace **f_convert.glsl** with

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D y_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

 void main()
{   
    float r, g, b, y, u, v;

    //We had put the Y values of each pixel to the R,G,B components by
    //GL_LUMINANCE, that's why we're pulling it from the R component,
    //we could also use G or B
    y = texture2D(y_texture, v_texCoord).r;

    //We had put the U and V values of each pixel to the A and R,G,B
    //components of the texture respectively using GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA.
    //Since U,V bytes are interspread in the texture, this is probably
    //the fastest way to use them in the shader
    u = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a - 0.5;
    v = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).r - 0.5;

    //The numbers are just YUV to RGB conversion constants
    r = y + 1.13983*v;
    g = y - 0.39465*u - 0.58060*v;
    b = y + 2.03211*u;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(r,g,b,1.0);
}
```