# Android YUV-RGB conversion in OpenGL ES 2.0 fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I'm trying to locate/figure out how to color covert a YUV texture (for instance YUV420P) to RGB in OpenGL ES 2.0 fragment shader code on android. I have found various pointers/tips but haven't been able to convert it correctly. Does anyone know if there are any sample working project(s) for android availble?

Comment: Also the Y, U and V data is bound to 3 different sampler2Ds `ysampler, usampelr and vsampler`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130790/yuv-to-rgb-convertion-by-fragment-shader