# libgdx return to menus stage after showing devicecamera

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-camera, shader

I want to use a qrcode scanner in my game. To render the preview I'm using the code in the following post:
[How to render Android's YUV-NV21 camera image on the background in libgdx with OpenGLES 2.0 in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456884/how-to-render-androids-yuv-nv21-camera-image-on-the-background-in-libgdx-with-o/22456885#22456885)

When the qrcode is scanned I want to return to the main menu. When I call destroy on the AndroidDependentCameraController it just freezes on the last image. How do I get my Stage to be shown again?

When I remove the following lines, it seems to be able to go back (sometimes) but the preview shows up blue

```
Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
Gdx.gl.glTexImage2D(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL20.GL_LUMINANCE, s.width, s.height, 0, GL20.GL_LUMINANCE, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yBuffer);
```