# OpenGLES Rendering Color Issue

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm quite new to OpenGLES. I am trying to render the Android camera frames (YUV) to a quad. I am using a similar approach as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456884/how-to-render-androids-yuv-nv21-camera-image-on-the-background-in-libgdx-with-o/22456885#22456885).

The issue is that I get this color issue as shown below. I don't think its a shader issue as I've tried other shaders and it has resulted in the same rendering.

[image]
[image]

Here's my rendering code:

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureYHandle);

GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
                mWidth, mHeight, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mBufferY);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureUVHandle);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA,
                mWidth/2, mHeight/2, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mBufferUV);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_NONE);




GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureYHandle);
mTextureYHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_InputImageTexture0");
GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureYHandle, 0);

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureUVHandle);
mTextureUVHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_InputImageTexture1");
GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUVHandle, 1);

GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Position");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                0, quadVertices);

mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoordinate");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                0, quadTextureCoordinates);

GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_NONE);

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_NONE);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yep. I have a handle to the program at all times.

Comment: It was a simple fix. I was assigning the same handle for Y and UV. When I created a new handle for them, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You fail to switch texture unit before submitting your UV buffer — it looks like you've omitted a `GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);`.

Assuming that's not a copy and paste error, it would overwrite your luminance texture, so you'd end up sampling the UV texture for both luminance and chrominance. I would expect that to give you very grey images though, as U and V have a range of (-0.5, 0.5), meaning that when rendered as bytes 0 in that is 128 in luminance.

Suggested diagnostic check: skip UV entirely, just upload and show Y as greyscale.

You can also skip rebinding of active textures to samplers when establishing shader inputs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the texture switching part. I've added that line to the code but doesn't seem to fix the issue. Let me see what happens when I remove the UV upload part and stick to Y alone. Also, when I remove the rebinding code, I get a blue screen.

Comment: Then is anything else happening in between? OpenGL being the modal pain that it is, could somebody be trampling your textures?

Comment: I tried creating a vec4 of y alone. But that's giving me a black screen. Shouldn't it change greys atleast? As I move my camera around?

Comment: I do a clearColor. Other than that, not doing anything else.

Comment: Yes, it should give you exactly a black and white image. UV are just extra information about colour. I assume that while debugging you've inspected `mBufferY` prior to upload and confirmed that it has a whole bunch of interesting values? What about if you set it entirely to e.g. 128 before upload?

Comment: I don't get a black and white image. I get plain black.Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's more efficient to use a `SurfaceTexture` to directly import the camera data as an EGLImage, and then use the `GL_OES_EGL_image_external` extension to access the YUV data natively via a `samplerExternalOES` in the fragment shader. This will handle color conversion and multi-plane sampling automatically and save you having to worry about it (as it can vary from platform to platform).