# YUV_420_888 (byte) format

Tags: android, arrays, yuv

I capture an image on Android in YUV_420_888 format (YCbCr).

Image dimension is **4032 X 3024** and I get three planes from the **ImageReader**.

> Y with 12192768 bytes
>  
>   U with 6096383 bytes 
>  
>   V with 6096383 bytes

My understanding is that for every pixel in **Y** there is a corresponding value in **U/V** planes with 2:1 ratio (2 pixel Y correspond to one pixel U/V).

But doing the math **12192768/2** there is one byte missing in **U/V** plane.

Why is that one byte missing? How is the relation between **Y** and **U/V** for Android **camera2 YUV_420_888.**

Answer (score 9):

Okay Let's try this again.  Originally I asked if anyone had found an answer as I was also looking for resolution on this. Finally though I've been able to figure our the answer to this question:

The answer lies in the image acquisition format.  Android till default to a NV21 format, meaning a V byte followed by a U byte interwoven plane after the Y plane.  NV12 is an alternate that has the U byte prior to the V byte (see: [How to render Android's YUV-NV21 camera image on the background in libgdx with OpenGLES 2.0 in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456884/how-to-render-androids-yuv-nv21-camera-image-on-the-background-in-libgdx-with-o))

The Image object returned by the ImageReader then creates a ByteBuffer which directly access's this memory location.  Calling isDirect() on the ByteBuffer verifies this. You can also see this by modifying vBuffer (getPlane()[2]) index 1.  Since index 1 of the vBuffer points to the same memory location of uBuffer index 0, the uBuffer.get(0) will be the same.

Thus the UV plane, VU plane for NV21, is equal to Y-plane/2=**length** (as noted 6096384 in the example above). If you start with the first V (VU-plane[0]) and count to the last V (VU-plane[length-1]), it will be one less because the last byte in this plane is U.  Likewise the first U byte is at index 1 of the VU-plane until VU-plane[length].

Here is an image that hopefully visually explains the above wording:
[image]

This is all predicated on the fact that the image is captured in NV21 format and not NV12, or Y12.  Here is another good visual for reference (https://www.twblogs.net/a/5d7ede57bd9eee541c3480f3)

Comment: Great answer, and extremely helpful to me - thank you, mister!