# OpenGL Convert NV12 to RGB24 using shader

Tags: opengl, colors, rgb, fragment-shader, yuv

I tried to write an application to display YUV image in OpenGL. I was successfully converted YUV to RGB in C++ using this snippet ([source](https://blog.csdn.net/subfate/article/details/47305147))

```
static long int crv_tab[256];   
static long int cbu_tab[256];   
static long int cgu_tab[256];   
static long int cgv_tab[256];   
static long int tab_76309[256]; 
static unsigned char clp[1024];   //for clip in CCIR601   

void init_yuv420p_table() 
{   
    long int crv,cbu,cgu,cgv;   
    int i,ind;      
    static int init = 0;

    if (init == 1) return;

    crv = 104597; cbu = 132201;  /* fra matrise i global.h */   
    cgu = 25675;  cgv = 53279;   

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)    
    {   
        crv_tab[i] = (i-128) * crv;   
        cbu_tab[i] = (i-128) * cbu;   
        cgu_tab[i] = (i-128) * cgu;   
        cgv_tab[i] = (i-128) * cgv;   
        tab_76309[i] = 76309*(i-16);   
    }   

    for (i = 0; i < 384; i++)   
        clp[i] = 0;   
    ind = 384;   
    for (i = 0;i < 256; i++)   
        clp[ind++] = i;   
    ind = 640;   
    for (i = 0;i < 384; i++)   
        clp[ind++] = 255;

    init = 1;
}

void yuv420sp_to_rgb24(YUV_TYPE type, unsigned char* yuvbuffer,unsigned char* rgbbuffer, int width,int height)   
{
    int y1, y2, u, v;    
    unsigned char *py1, *py2;   
    int i, j, c1, c2, c3, c4;   
    unsigned char *d1, *d2;   
    unsigned char *src_u;
    static int init_yuv420p = 0;

    src_u = yuvbuffer + width * height;   // u

    py1 = yuvbuffer;   // y
    py2 = py1 + width;   
    d1 = rgbbuffer;   
    d2 = d1 + 3 * width;   

    init_yuv420p_table();

    for (j = 0; j < height; j += 2)    
    {    
        for (i = 0; i < width; i += 2)    
        {
            if (type ==  FMT_NV12)
            {
                u = *src_u++;   
                v = *src_u++;      // v紧跟u，在u的下一个位置
            }
            if (type == FMT_NV21)
            {
                v = *src_u++;   
                u = *src_u++;      // u紧跟v，在v的下一个位置
            }

            c1 = crv_tab[v];   
            c2 = cgu_tab[u];   
            c3 = cgv_tab[v];   
            c4 = cbu_tab[u];   

            //up-left   
            y1 = tab_76309[*py1++];    
            *d1++ = clp[384+((y1 + c1)>>16)];     
            *d1++ = clp[384+((y1 - c2 - c3)>>16)];   
            *d1++ = clp[384+((y1 + c4)>>16)];   

            //down-left   
            y2 = tab_76309[*py2++];   
            *d2++ = clp[384+((y2 + c1)>>16)];     
            *d2++ = clp[384+((y2 - c2 - c3)>>16)];   
            *d2++ = clp[384+((y2 + c4)>>16)];   

            //up-right   
            y1 = tab_76309[*py1++];   
            *d1++ = clp[384+((y1 + c1)>>16)];     
            *d1++ = clp[384+((y1 - c2 - c3)>>16)];   
            *d1++ = clp[384+((y1 + c4)>>16)];   

            //down-right   
            y2 = tab_76309[*py2++];   
            *d2++ = clp[384+((y2 + c1)>>16)];     
            *d2++ = clp[384+((y2 - c2 - c3)>>16)];   
            *d2++ = clp[384+((y2 + c4)>>16)];   
        }
        d1  += 3*width;
        d2  += 3*width;
        py1 += width;
        py2 += width;
    }
}
```

In order to make my application runs smoother, instead of doing the conversion on the CPU, I do it in the fragment shader.

I separate the YUV buffer into Y_Buffer[width*height], U_Buffer[width*height/4] and V_Buffer[width*height/4] from the interleaved UV_Buffer[width*height/2] and pass it to the fragment shader. (I intended to pass the Y_Buffer and the UV_Buffer with the type *format* GL_RED and GL_RG respectively by using glTexImage2D but somehow when I read the G channel of the UV_Texture in the fragment shader, it always returns 0).

Below is the conversion in the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D textureY;
uniform sampler2D textureU;
uniform sampler2D textureV;
void main() {
    vec3 yuv, rgb;
    vec3 yuv2r = vec3(1.164, 0.0, 1.596);
    vec3 yuv2g = vec3(1.164, -0.391, -0.813);
    vec3 yuv2b = vec3(1.164, 2.018, 0.0);

    yuv.x = texture(textureY, texCoord).r - 0.0625;
    yuv.y = texture(textureU, texCoord).r - 0.5;
    yuv.z = texture(textureV, texCoord).r - 0.5;

    rgb.x = dot(yuv, yuv2r);
    rgb.y = dot(yuv, yuv2g);
    rgb.z = dot(yuv, yuv2b);

    FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
}
```

But all I got is green and pink pixels. I'm quite a newbie in OpenGL. Can anyone point out where I may be wrong? Your help is appreciated.

**Update: Add codes that load texture**

```
FILE fp = fopen("nv21.raw", "rb");
unsigned char *yuvBuffer = new unsigned char[width*height*3/2];
fread(yuvBuffer, 1, width*height*3/2, fp);

unsigned char *vuBuffer = &yuvBuffer[width*height];

int bufSize = width*height/4;
unsigned char *uBuffer = new unsigned char[bufSize];
memset(uBuffer, 0, bufSize);
unsigned char *vBuffer = new unsigned char[bufSize];
memset(vBuffer, 0, bufSize);

unsigned char *uPtr, *vPtr;
uPtr = uBuffer;
vPtr = vBuffer;

for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++)
{
    *vPtr = *vuBuffer++;
    *uPtr = *vuBuffer++;
}

GLuint textureID[3];

glGenTextures(1, &textureID[0]);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &yuvBuffer[0]);
glBindTexture(0);

glGenTextures(1, &textureID[1]);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[1]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width/2, height/2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, uBuffer);
glBindTexture(0);

glGenTextures(1, &textureID[2]);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[2]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width/2, height/2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vBuffer);
glBindTexture(0);
```

Comment: The shader doesn't seem to be the issue. You have to show the code, that creates the texture images and that code that sets the texture sampler uniforms.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I just edited, please take a look

Comment: Why `width/4`? Where do you assign the index of the texture unit to the texture sampler uniform?

Comment: @Rabbid76 `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0), glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1), glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2)` will be linked to `textureY, textureU, textureV` respectively by opengl

Comment: @Rabbid76 sorry, it should be `width/2` and `height/2`

Comment: *"will be linked to textureY, textureU, textureV respectively by opengl "* - No that won't happen automatically. You have to assign 0, 1, 2 (by [`glUniform1i`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml)) to the sampler uniforms `textureY`, `textureU`, `textureV`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 OMGGGGG, thank you so much, this killing for hours. Can you write an answer then I will accept it

Comment: Why title is `NV12`? That code look like `YUV420`

Comment: @TrươngQuốcKhánh it's basically the same. Just different interleaved i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the texture samplers in the shader program are associated to texture unit 0 (default value is 0).
You have to assign the index of the texture unit to the texture sampler uniforms, by [`glUniform1i`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml). The texture unit is the binding point between the [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)) and the [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture) object. e.g.:

```cpp
GLint locTexY = glGetUniformLocation(program, "textureY");
GLint locTexU = glGetUniformLocation(program, "textureU");
GLint locTexV = glGetUniformLocation(program, "textureV");
```

```cpp
glUseProgram(program);
glUniform1i(locTexY, 0); // corresponds to GL_TEXTURE0
glUniform1i(locTexU, 1); // corresponds to GL_TEXTURE1
glUniform1i(locTexV, 2); // corresponds to GL_TEXTURE2
```

---

Since OpenGL 4.20, the [Binding points](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points) can be set in-shader by [Layout Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)):

```c
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D textureY;
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D textureU;
layout(binding = 2) uniform sampler2D textureV;
```