# Rendering camera preview in GLSurfaceView issue in Samsung Galaxy S6 OS 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-camera, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I made a sample project for rendering camera preview YUV data in GLSurfaceView. The reference which I've used is [YUV to RGB conversion by fragment shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130790/yuv-to-rgb-conversion-by-fragment-shader?rq=1) . In this I just take camera preview data in YUV-NV21 formate and convert it to RGB using OpenGL fragment shader. Then render data in GLSurfaceView. I make it working successfully for Samsung S5, Nexus 4(5.1.1), Samsung J5 and LG p2. But when i test it in Samsung Galaxy S6(5.1.1) the screen has become dark. I have no idea where is the problem. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry for my bad english.

My project link https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptsvcwqjd07cj96/NewTryRender.zip?dl=0

Comment: I'm not sure what "screen has become dark" means. Assuming that means the color conversion isn't working correctly, you need to look at a hex dump of your input, look at a hex dump of your output, and figure out what went wrong.

Comment: If the color conversion isn't correct then how it work and render correctly in Samsung S5, Nexus 4(5.1.1), Samsung J5 and LG p2?